# how to call functions of (function (f, h) after images loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This article taken from [here](http://www.albanx.com/cubeslider/examples1.php). It is simple responsive cube with rotating. Normally images are from `<div id="cs-slider">img1 img2... < /div>`. Now here i wanted to load these from images folder automatically. Like all images from images folder.

Here, i tried for this like below code.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "task.php",
           data: {
               'files': 'images'
           },
           success: function (datas) {

              var res = datas.split(",");

              var len = (res).length;var k=0;

              res.forEach(function (entry) {

                   if (entry != '') {

                        $('#cs-slider').prepend('<img   src="images/'+entry+'" />');

                   }
                   k++;
                   if(k==len)
                   {
                    alert("hai3");
                   }

               }); 
              // alert(filelist);
           },
           error: function (req) {
               alert('Error: ' + req.status);
           }

});
```

But these are appending after page loaded.

How to solve this? 
Code is attached here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JsL27/)

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, all you need is onload event. 
Images will be shown after loading.

```
var img_ = new Image(); 
img_.onload = function() {
  $('#cs-slider').prepend('<img src="images/'+entry+'" />');
}
img_.src = '/images/'+entry;
```

Comment: thanks, i mean here i want to load images before  (function ($) )(jquery) function.